# Accessing data in a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, listbox

Hey I need to access items in my listbox I've made in WPF. What I have right now is the user can add a new class object to ObservableCollection which the ListBox.ItemsSource is bound to. This class has data in it where that data is used in things like a combobox, a text box and other simple things like that.

What i've made is really based off of one of the tut videos from windowsclient.net

```
    //Here's What I have so far
    <ListBox x:Name="MyList" Width = "300" Height = 300">
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ItemName" 
                         Text={Binding Path=PersonName}/>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="NumberOfRes" 
                         SelectedIndex="0"
                         SelectionChanged="NumberOfRes_SelectionChanged"
                         ItemsSource={Binding Path=ListOfNums}/>
                   </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    //ListOfNums
    private ObservableCollection<int> _listofNums = 
                     new ObservableCollection<int>()
    { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    public ObservableCollection<int> ListOfNums
    {
         get{return _listOfNums;}
    }

    //class Resident
    public class Resident
    {
        public string personName {get;set;}
    }
```

So I have that working. I have a button that adds a new class object and each object has it's data set properly through data binding. So I can see my default personName when a new object is added and I have a comboBox filled with integers from ListOfNums.

My propblem though is that I don't know how to access what these 'sub objects' (forgive me I'm new to WPF and don't know the proper term) are selecting. I want to know what my comboBox's SelectedItem is when a selectionChange event is raised or what my new personName is set to when the user types something into the textBox. So a user selects one of these ItemTemplate objects in the listBox and this item has a combobox and other UI controls that the user clicks. When the user clicks on one of these UI controls some data changes.

I've tried `((Resident)MyList.SelectedItem).personName` and a couple other methods just to see if I can access the data and manipulate it. Now the funny thing is that my comboBox in the ItemTemplate has a selection changed event that is called when the selection is changed, but I can't access the data!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomlish what you are after. The easiest approach would be to put a `SelectedItem` property on your ViewModel.

Your VieWModel would then look like this...

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
      ObservableCollection<Resident> Residents { get; }

      private Resident _selectedItem;
      public Resident SelectedItem
      {
           get { return _selectedItem; }
           set
           {
                _selectedItem = value;
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if(handler != null)
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedItem");
           }
      }
}
```

In your View set the `DataContext` to an instance of this `ViewModel`, where your `ListBox.ItemsSource` is bound to `Residents` and your `ListBox.SelectedItem` is bound to `SelectedItem`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Residents}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Selectedtem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

If you want to perform manipulation when the selection changes, note the setter of your `SelectedItem` property, which will contain the newly selected item.

**EDIT**:

Just noticed that your `Resident` model does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which it will need to do to propagate changes down stream. You can then get the point at which the data will change within the setter of a given property as mentioned with the `SelectedItem` property.

Comment: No it does. I have a ViewModelBase class that inherits from it, and thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Below sample uses a ViewModel (VM). If you add new residents to the Residents collection they will show up in the listbox. Just a tip, if you end up naming your controls a lot you are not doing data binding correctly.

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Residents}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PersonName}" />
                <ComboBox 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ListOfNums, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" 
                    SelectionChanged="NumberOfRes_SelectionChanged" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new VM();
    }

    private void NumberOfRes_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        Resident resident = comboBox.DataContext as Resident;
        int number = (int)comboBox.SelectedItem;
    }
}

public class VM
{
    public VM()
    {
        Residents = new ObservableCollection<Resident>() { new Resident() { PersonName = "AAA" }, new Resident() { PersonName = "BBB" } };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Resident> Residents { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<int> ListOfNums
    {
        get { return new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }; }
    }
}

public class Resident
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```